# How to find the average of numbers inputted from command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to write a bash shell script to get an average (rounded to 2 points) of the integer arguments given through the command line. One of the requirements is that I have to use a loop and at least one variable. For example, -50, 0, 50 and 100 should output 25.00.

Here is what I have (getting errors):

```
#!/bin/bash

sum = 0

if [ $* -ls 1 ]; then
 echo "no numbers inputted"
 exit 1

for number in $*; do
 sum += number

avg = $(echo "$sum / $* | bc -l")

printf "Average input = %.2f\n" $avg
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Have you read the `bash` documentation on handling numbers?

Comment: I put " " between $* and -eq 0 on the if statement.
What I am getting is:

sum: =: No such file or directory
sum: 0: No such file or directory
./avg.sh: line 15: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Numeric `+=` must be enclosed in `((...))`.

Comment: Consider running this through [shellcheck](http://shellcheck,net) first, it'll point out missing `fi`/`done`, spaces around assignment operators and other common issues. You can then ask about the remaining problems here.

Comment: Used shellcheck. Here is what I have now:

#!/bin/bash

sum=0 #sets the sum as 0

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then # if the arguments are 0. Exit.
 echo "no numbers inputted"
 exit 1
fi

for number in $#; do # loops through the number of arguements and adds th$
 ((sum=sum+number))
done

avg=$(echo "$sum / $# | bc -l") # gets average of sum

printf "Average input = %.2f\n" $avg # prints average of sum

The errors I am getting are:

Comment: For one thing, your for-loop isn't closed with a 'done' statement.

Comment: Please show your code and the *exact* errors. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: Don't expect readers to decipher code in comments. Update your Q so it is readable with your best attempt at solving your problem. Are you user `[ $* -ls 1 ]` is doing what you think it should? Good luck.

Comment: Did you mean `$#` in the first test and in the division?  And `"$@"`in the `for` loop?  It looks like you've been writing too much Perl lately.

Answer (score 0):

easy script :

```
#!/bin/bash

sum=0
for number in $*  
do 
    sum=$(expr $sum + $number)
done 

av=$(echo $sum / $# | bc -l)

echo "sum = $sum"  
echo "av = $av"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind taking a dependency on Python, you could try:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/stddev.html  You could just grep for the arithmetic mean:

```
$ seq 10000 | ./stddev
below cmd output started 2018 Sun Jan 21 11:57:25 AM PST
minimum 1
maximum 10000
range 9999
count 10000
sum 50005000
arithmetic_mean 5000.5
geometric_mean 3680.8271822200186
median 5000.5
mode none
standard_deviation 2,886.751332
median_absolute_deviation 2,500.000000
mean_absolute_deviation 2,500.000000
```